# TypeError: Cannot read property 'year' of undefined

Tags: javascript, datetime, d3.js

I am trying to create an interactive line chart with mouseover function. When you place your mouse over the line you can see the value of the GDP and the year at that certain point. But for some reason,I am getting the below error but I am not sure why it is happening as i am passing the right format data-set into the function.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'year' of undefined
```

My code is below:

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<htmL>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <head>
    <style>
      .line-chart2{
        margin-top:200px;
        margin-left:100px;
        border:1px solid lightgray;
      }
      circle {
        fill: steelblue;
      }
      body { 
        font: 12px Arial;}
      path { 
        stroke: steelblue;
        stroke-width: 2;
        fill: none;
      }
      .axis path,
      .axis line {
        fill: none;
        stroke: grey;
        stroke-width: 1;
        shape-rendering: crispEdges;
      }

      div.tooltip { 
          position: absolute;           
          text-align: center;           
          width: 80px;                  
          height: 64px;                 
          padding: 2px;             
          font: 14px sans-serif;
          color: black;     
          background: lightsteelblue;   
          border: 0px;      
          border-radius: 8px;           
          pointer-events: none;         
      }
      .overlay {
          fill: none;
          pointer-events: all;
        }
      .focus circle {
        fill: #F1F3F3;
        stroke: #6F257F;
        stroke-width: 5px;
      }
      .hover-line {
        stroke: #6F257F;
        stroke-width: 2px;
        stroke-dasharray: 3,3;
      }

  </style>

  </head>
  <body>
      <svg class='line-chart2'></svg>
      <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script> 
      <script src="math.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
      <script src="./regression.js"></script>
  </body>
</htmL>
```

Javascript

```
var gdp=[ 387.65,   410.32,  415.73,  452.69,  462.14,
  478.96,  508.06,  599.59,  699.68,  808.90,
  920.31, 1201.11, 1186.95, 1323.94, 1656.61,
 1823.04, 1827.63, 1856.72, 2039.12,  2102.39,
 2274.22, 2600.81]; //y or GDP of India
var years=['1996','1997','1998','1999','2000','2001','2002','2003','2004','2005','2006','2007','2008','2009','2010','2011','2012','2013','2014','2015','2016','2017'];

var data_gdp=[]
  for(i=0;i<forexp.length;i++){
    data_gdp.push({year:years[i],value:gdp[i]})
    }

function drawChart_gdp(data,class_name) {
  var svgWidth = 1200, svgHeight = 400;
  var margin = { top: 60, right: 60, bottom: 60, left: 60 };
  var width = svgWidth - margin.left - margin.right;
  var height = svgHeight - margin.top - margin.bottom;
  var svg = d3.select(class_name)
    .attr("width", svgWidth)
    .attr("height", svgHeight);
  var bisectDate= d3.bisector(function(d) { return d.year; }).left;
  var g = svg.append("g")
    .attr("transform", 
       "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")"
    );
  var x = d3.scaleTime().range([0,width]);
  var y = d3.scaleLinear().rangeRound([height, 0]);

  var line = d3.line()
   .x(function(d) { return x(new Date(parseInt(d.year),0))})
   .y(function(d) { return y(d.value)})
   x.domain(d3.extent(data, function (d) { return new Date(parseInt(d.year),0); }));
   y.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.value }));

   g.append("g")
   .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
   .call(d3.axisBottom(x))
   .append("text")
    .attr("fill", "#000")
    .text("Year")
    .attr("dy", "1.90em")
    .attr("y", 5)
    .attr("x",500)
    .attr("font-size", "20px")
    .select(".domain")
    .remove();

   g.append("g")
   .call(d3.axisLeft(y))
   .append("text")
   .attr("fill", "#000")
   .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
   .attr("y", -80)
   .attr("x",-55)
   .attr("dy", "1.90em")
   .attr("text-anchor", "center")
   .attr("font-size", "20px")
   .text("GDP ($)")

  g.append("path")
   .datum(data)
   .attr("fill", "none")
   .attr("stroke", "steelblue")
   .attr("stroke-linejoin", "round")
   .attr("stroke-linecap", "round")
   .attr("stroke-width", 1.5)
   .attr("d", line);

   var focus = g.append("g")
   .attr("class", "focus")
   .style("display", "none");

  focus.append("line")
    .attr("class", "x-hover-line hover-line")
    .attr("y1", 0)
    .attr("y2", height);

  focus.append("line")
    .attr("class", "y-hover-line hover-line")
    .attr("x1", width)
    .attr("x2", width);

  focus.append("circle")
    .attr("r", 7.5);

  focus.append("text")
    .attr("x", 15)
    .attr("dy", ".31em");

  svg.append("rect")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")")
    .attr("class", "overlay")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height)
    .on("mouseover", function() { focus.style("display", null); })
    .on("mouseout", function() { focus.style("display", "none"); })
    .on("mousemove",  function() { //problem in this function
      var x0 = x.invert(d3.mouse(this)[0]),
          i = bisectDate(data, x0, 1),
          d0 = data[i - 1],
          d1 = data[i],
          d = x0 - d0.year > d1.year - x0 ? d1 : d0;
      focus.attr("transform", "translate(" + x(d.year) + "," + y(d.value) + ")");
      focus.select("text").text(function() { return d.value; });
      focus.select(".x-hover-line").attr("y2", height - y(d.value));
      focus.select(".y-hover-line").attr("x2", width + width);
     });

  }
drawChart_gdp(data_gdp,'.line-chart2');
```

Comment: is `i` ever `0` or `>data.length`? `data` would return undefined rather than an object in those cases

Comment: @JacobThomas I don't think that is the problem as I am using a bisector function there to return an index!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `x` is a time scale, the returned value of...

```
var x0 = x.invert(d3.mouse(this)[0])
```

... is a **date object**, like this:

```
Fri Nov 29 1996 19:56:00
```

However, in your data, you have **strings**:

```
[{year: "1996", value: 387.65}, {year: "1997", value: 410.32} etc...];
```

The solution is quite straightforward, just format the dates:

```
var x0 = d3.timeFormat("%Y")(x.invert(d3.mouse(this)[0]))
```

Here is your code with that change:

```js
var gdp = [387.65, 410.32, 415.73, 452.69, 462.14,
  478.96, 508.06, 599.59, 699.68, 808.90,
  920.31, 1201.11, 1186.95, 1323.94, 1656.61,
  1823.04, 1827.63, 1856.72, 2039.12, 2102.39,
  2274.22, 2600.81
]; //y or GDP of India
var years = ['1996', '1997', '1998', '1999', '2000', '2001', '2002', '2003', '2004', '2005', '2006', '2007', '2008', '2009', '2010', '2011', '2012', '2013', '2014', '2015', '2016', '2017'];

var data_gdp = []
for (i = 0; i < years.length; i++) {
  data_gdp.push({
    year: years[i],
    value: gdp[i]
  })
}

function drawChart_gdp(data, class_name) {
  var svgWidth = 1200,
    svgHeight = 400;
  var margin = {
    top: 60,
    right: 60,
    bottom: 60,
    left: 60
  };
  var width = svgWidth - margin.left - margin.right;
  var height = svgHeight - margin.top - margin.bottom;
  var svg = d3.select(class_name)
    .attr("width", svgWidth)
    .attr("height", svgHeight);
  var bisectDate = d3.bisector(function(d) {
    return d.year;
  }).left;
  var g = svg.append("g")
    .attr("transform",
      "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")"
    );
  var x = d3.scaleTime().range([0, width]);
  var y = d3.scaleLinear().rangeRound([height, 0]);

  var line = d3.line()
    .x(function(d) {
      return x(new Date(parseInt(d.year), 0))
    })
    .y(function(d) {
      return y(d.value)
    })
  x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) {
    return new Date(parseInt(d.year), 0);
  }));
  y.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) {
    return d.value
  }));

  g.append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
    .call(d3.axisBottom(x))
    .append("text")
    .attr("fill", "#000")
    .text("Year")
    .attr("dy", "1.90em")
    .attr("y", 5)
    .attr("x", 500)
    .attr("font-size", "20px")
    .select(".domain")
    .remove();

  g.append("g")
    .call(d3.axisLeft(y))
    .append("text")
    .attr("fill", "#000")
    .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
    .attr("y", -80)
    .attr("x", -55)
    .attr("dy", "1.90em")
    .attr("text-anchor", "center")
    .attr("font-size", "20px")
    .text("GDP ($)")

  g.append("path")
    .datum(data)
    .attr("fill", "none")
    .attr("stroke", "steelblue")
    .attr("stroke-linejoin", "round")
    .attr("stroke-linecap", "round")
    .attr("stroke-width", 1.5)
    .attr("d", line);

  var focus = g.append("g")
    .attr("class", "focus")
    .style("display", "none");

  focus.append("line")
    .attr("class", "x-hover-line hover-line")
    .attr("y1", 0)
    .attr("y2", height);

  focus.append("line")
    .attr("class", "y-hover-line hover-line")
    .attr("x1", width)
    .attr("x2", width);

  focus.append("circle")
    .attr("r", 7.5);

  focus.append("text")
    .attr("x", 15)
    .attr("dy", ".31em");

  svg.append("rect")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")")
    .attr("class", "overlay")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height)
    .on("mouseover", function() {
      focus.style("display", null);
    })
    .on("mouseout", function() {
      focus.style("display", "none");
    })
    .on("mousemove", function() { //problem in this function
      var x0 = d3.timeFormat("%Y")(x.invert(d3.mouse(this)[0])),
        i = bisectDate(data, x0, 1);
      d0 = data[i - 1],
        d1 = data[i],
        d = x0 - d0.year > d1.year - x0 ? d1 : d0;
      focus.attr("transform", "translate(" + x(d.year) + "," + y(d.value) + ")");
      focus.select("text").text(function() {
        return d.value;
      });
      focus.select(".x-hover-line").attr("y2", height - y(d.value));
      focus.select(".y-hover-line").attr("x2", width + width);
    });

}
drawChart_gdp(data_gdp, '.line-chart2');
```

```html
<head>
  <style>
    circle {
      fill: steelblue;
    }
    
    body {
      font: 12px Arial;
    }
    
    path {
      stroke: steelblue;
      stroke-width: 2;
      fill: none;
    }
    
    .axis path,
    .axis line {
      fill: none;
      stroke: grey;
      stroke-width: 1;
      shape-rendering: crispEdges;
    }
    
    div.tooltip {
      position: absolute;
      text-align: center;
      width: 80px;
      height: 64px;
      padding: 2px;
      font: 14px sans-serif;
      color: black;
      background: lightsteelblue;
      border: 0px;
      border-radius: 8px;
      pointer-events: none;
    }
    
    .overlay {
      fill: none;
      pointer-events: all;
    }
    
    .focus circle {
      fill: #F1F3F3;
      stroke: #6F257F;
      stroke-width: 5px;
    }
    
    .hover-line {
      stroke: #6F257F;
      stroke-width: 2px;
      stroke-dasharray: 3, 3;
    }
  </style>

</head>

<body>
  <svg class='line-chart2'></svg>
  <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
</body>
```